# Make tabs acts like a toggle

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to have an ionic app with a page with 2 tabs: (a)  Current (b) Old

However, the content of both these pages is very similar - getting some data from Firebase where all data shown on page (a) is not shown on page (b)  and vice versa. So effectively the tabs acts like a toggle to determine which data is shown.

How can i not duplicate all the code for getting the data from firebase and selecting which one to display between the two pages for `Current` and `Old`  ?

i was thinking like if the two tab pages could share the .ts file which has the array of items to display and then a variable like `boolean tabA` which is to keep track of which tab is on.

or is there an easier solution like how to get the selected tab and then change the page content using that?

please guide me on what is the best thing to do

Answer (score -1):

i thought of two good solutions in your situation.

1) make a service that has these functions ready and just inject it in the .ts file of each component, which will make the code much smaller.

2)or close to what you said, have both as one component and make a boolean variable to determine which one is it, and let some of the .html code be in  or *ngIf with a condition of this boolean variable.